# Using JS to toggle Bootstrap accordion

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I'm trying to trigger a Bootsrap 4 accordion / tab pane using JS from a link outside the list structure. I'm tryting using data attributes to jump to the tab pane, and JQuery to toggle the accordion as I can't see how to do both with data attributes (correct me if you can). My link displays the correct tab pane, but it doesn't expand the accordion:

HTML:

```
<a id="standToggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#stand-visual" href="#stand-visual">Trigger accordion tab</a>

<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link nav-has-child" data-toggle="collapse" href=".collapseStandBuild" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseStandBuild">Stand Build &amp; Information</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item nav-sub-item collapse collapseStandBuild">
  <a class="nav-link" id="stand-visual-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#stand-visual" role="tab" aria-controls="stand-visual" aria-selected="false">Stand Visual</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item nav-sub-item collapse collapseStandBuild">
  <a class="nav-link" id="stand-av-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#stand-av" role="tab" aria-controls="stand-av" aria-selected="false">Stand AV</a>
</li>

<div class="tab-pane fade" id="stand-visual" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="stand-visual-tab">
  ...
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="stand-av" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="stand-av-tab">
  ...
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
// toggle accordion on link click
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#standToggle").click(function(){
   $("#stand-visual").collapse('toggle'); // toggle collapse
  });
});
```

How do I get this working?